# html 5 video - cross platform

Tags: android, html, html5-video

I have problem with html 5 video tag,
I try this code:

```
<video id="SrcVideo" width="100%" height="240" style="max-width:460px; width:98%;" autoplay="true" poster="sound_icon.jpg">
    <source style="width: 100%;" src="MyVid.m4v">
    <source style="width: 100%;" src="MyVid.m4v" type="video/mp4">
    <object width="100%" data="http://releases.flowplayer.org/swf/flowplayer-3.2.1.swf" type="application/x-shockwave-flash">
    <param name="movie" value="http://releases.flowplayer.org/swf/flowplayer-3.2.1.swf">
    <param name="allowFullScreen" value="true">
    <param name="wmode" value="transparent">
    <param name="flashVars" value="config={'playlist':['',{'url':'MyVid.flv','autoPlay':false}]}">
    </object>
</video>
```

It seems to be working on iPhone,
And on Android's chrome and dolphin,
But on the stock android browser it doesn't work, I can hear the audio but can't see the video.

I have used this guide to encode the video correctly:

http://www.broken-links.com/2010/07/08/making-html5-video-work-on-android-phones/

Comment: It's probably an issue with the browser not being able to play the video's encoding.  Have you read through this article?  http://www.broken-links.com/2010/07/30/encoding-video-for-android/